# Early binding against late binding

Tags: vb.net, oop, object, binding

I just turned on the such option strict and discovered issues I wasn't use to deal with such as **late binding**. Indeed the following lines create a late binding error

```
Dim available_ports As Array
available_ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames()
If available_ports(0).ToString <> "" Then...
```

I know that an object is **early bound** when it is assigned to a variable declared to be of a specific object type.

I have tried several ideas but wasn't able to deal with this error. How to early bound the last line of this code?

The most interresting thing I made was

```
Dim available_ports As String
```

The error on the last line disappeared but a new one appeared on the second line to tell me it was impossible to convert `String ()` in `String`

Comment: What exactly is the error message ? Which line is it exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the method [GetPortNames()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a String Array. The class Array does not really match, and String is not an Array...

```
Dim available_ports As String()
```

should workd